# SEQUEL Viewpoint Query Error

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I am working on the SEQUEL VIEWPOINT for the first time and i have created this query where i have AcctNo. as derived field.

```
    SELECT Cat(substr(cat("000",digits(i0nrov.cbi0rep)),length(cat("000",digits(i0nrov.cbi0rep)))-2,3),substr(cat("000000000",digits(i0cnbr.cbi0rep)),length(cat("000000000",digits(i0cnbr.cbi0rep)))-8,9))NAME(Acctno) COLHDG("Accnt Number"),
                    i0cnbr.cbi0rep NAME(PreAccNo) COLHDG("Pre Accnt Num" "Number"),
                    i0cnbr.cbi0repres NAME(PostAccNo) COLHDG("Post Accnt Num" "Number"), 
                    SUM(i0a01) NAME(PreARBal) COLHDG(" Pre A/R Bal ") EDTCDE(L), SUM(i0a01) NAME(PostARBal) COLHDG("Post A/R Bal") EDTCDE(L)
         FROM           bakbosfile/cbi0rep,auditsql/xrfcmpfres,auditsql/cbi0repres
         INNER JOIN     Acctno=cxgcus.xrfcmpfres and cxcnbr.xrfcmpfres=i0cnbr.cbi0repres
         GROUP BY   Acctno,PreAccNo,PostAccNo
         HAVING         SUM(I0A01.cbi0rep)<>SUM(I0A01.cbi0repres)
         UNION ALL 
    SELECT          Cat(substr(cat("000",digits(i0nrov.cbi0rep)),length(cat("000",digits(i0nrov.cbi0rep)))-2,3),substr(cat("000000000",digits(i0cnbr.cbi0rep)),length(cat("000000000",digits(i0cnbr.cbi0rep)))-8,9))NAME(Acctno) COLHDG("Accnt Number"),
                    i0cnbr.cbi0rep NAME(PreAccNo) COLHDG("Pre Accnt Num" "Number"), 
                    i0cnbr.cbi0repbus NAME(PostAccNo) COLHDG("Post Accnt Num" "Number"), 
                    SUM(i0a01) NAME(PreARBal) COLHDG(" Pre A/R Bal ") EDTCDE(L), SUM(i0a01) NAME(PostARBal) COLHDG("Post A/R Bal") EDTCDE(L)
         FROM           bakbosfile/cbi0rep,auditsql/xrfcmpfbus,auditsql/cbi0repbus
         INNER JOIN     Acctno=cxgcus.xrfcmpfbus and cxcnbr.xrfcmpfbus=i0cnbr.cbi0repbus
         GROUP BY   Acctno,PreAccNo,PostAccNo
         HAVING         SUM(I0A01.cbi0rep)<>SUM(I0A01.cbi0repbus)
```

Please help! I am getting below error:
[image: Error SEQUEL Viewpoint]

Hello Buck Thank you for the reply but it is not recognizing 2 JOIN in the statement so i have changed the query to :

```
SELECT          Cat(substr(cat("000",digits(i0nrov.cbi0rep)),length(cat("000",digits(i0nrov.cbi0rep)))-2,3),substr(cat("000000000",digits(i0cnbr.cbi0rep)),length(cat("000000000",digits(i0cnbr.cbi0rep)))-8,9)) NAME(Acctno) COLHDG("Accnt Number"), 
            i0cnbr.cbi0rep NAME(PreAccNo) COLHDG("Pre Accnt Num" "Number"), i0cnbr.cbi0repres NAME(PostAccNo) COLHDG("Post Accnt Num" "Number"), 
            SUM(i0a01) NAME(PreARBal) COLHDG(" Pre A/R Bal ") EDTCDE(L), SUM(i0a01) NAME(PostARBal) COLHDG("Post A/R Bal") EDTCDE(L)
 FROM           bakbosfile/cbi0rep,auditsql/xrfcmpfres, auditsql/cbi0repres
 INNER JOIN     Cat(substr(cat("000",digits(i0nrov.cbi0rep)),length(cat("000",digits(i0nrov.cbi0rep)))-2,3),substr(cat("000000000",digits(i0cnbr.cbi0rep)),length(cat("000000000",digits(i0cnbr.cbi0rep)))-8,9)) 
                =cxgcus.xrfcmpfres AND cxcnbr.xrfcmpfres=i0cnbr.cbi0repres
 GROUP BY   Acctno,PreAccNo,PostAccNo
 HAVING         SUM(I0A01.cbi0rep)<>SUM(I0A01.cbi0repres)
```

But getting error:
[image]

Comment: what DBMS are you using? this is not standard [tag:sql] syntax, or at least none that I can recognize.

Comment: MySQL and DB2, not a very common combination?

Comment: I have the same issue. I am not sure which database it is using on the backend. SEQUEL viewpoint in the tool for IBM-AS400 so i am assuming it is DB2 database. SEQUEL viewpoint is a tool wizard to create queries.

Comment: replace `INNER JOIN` with `WHERE` and try again, I'm not familiar with db2 sql syntax, but it looks to me that you tried to mix, ANSI-89 and ANSI-92 sql standards.

Comment: @Prat14 did you just tried to replace `INNER JOIN` with `WHERE` clause? I think you should be able to that on your original query.

Comment: Yes i tried that it did not work as it has to satisfy join condition.

Comment: The JOIN syntax is not right.  If you want to use a list of tables like FROM TABLEA, TABLEB, TABLEC you must put the join criteria in the WHERE clause.  This is an old fashioned way to do it but if you want to do that you must change INNER JOIN to WHERE, as @VladimirOselsky suggested.

Comment: Can you list your structure to show files and columns?

Answer (score 0):

If this is going to DB2 for i, the typical syntax is:

```
SELECT Cat(substr(cat("000",digits(i0nrov.cbi0rep)),length(cat("000",digits(i0nrov.cbi0rep)))-2,3),substr(cat("000000000",digits(i0cnbr.cbi0rep)),length(cat 
                ("000000000",digits(i0cnbr.cbi0rep)))-8,9)) as acctno, ...
FROM bakbosfile/cbi0rep 
  JOIN auditsql/xrfcmpfres on Cat(substr(cat("000",digits(i0nrov.cbi0rep)),length(cat("000",digits(i0nrov.cbi0rep)))-2,3),substr(cat("000000000",digits(i0cnbr.cbi0rep)),length(cat 
                ("000000000",digits(i0cnbr.cbi0rep)))-8,9))=cxgcus.xrfcmpfres 
  JOIN auditsql/cbi0repres on cxcnbr.xrfcmpfres=i0cnbr.cbi0repres
```

IBM documentation is found in the [Knowledge Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i/welcome).  You didn't mention what version of IBM i you are connecting to, so [here is an elderly DB2 for I reference](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_i5_54/db2/rbafzmst02.htm).